# Superpowered Decoder for remote URL

Tags: superpowered

I have successfully decoded a local file using Superpowered

```
SuperpoweredDecoder *decoder = new SuperpoweredDecoder();
const char *openError = decoder->open("/Users/john/Desktop/myFile.mp3", false, 0, 0);

    if (openError) {
        NSLog(@"open error: %s", openError);
        delete decoder;
        return 0;
    };
```

Now I'd like to do the same with a remote URL

eg. by replacing the decoder->open call with...

```
 const char *openError = decoder->open("https://example.com/api/mobile/courses/redirect/Z3VpZpZGVvcy9qbTMwYWJnLTAwMS5tcDM%3D?courseid=678");
```

(I've changed the URL a bit here as it's not a URL I should be releasing, however, I have confirmed that the URL was good by pasting it into Chrome address bar - Chrome plays the mp3)

**the result:** *open error: @*

The Superpowered documentation describes path as:   Full file system path **or progressive download path (http or https).** so I thought this might be possible.

Do I need to be setting *customHTTPHeaders* - if so, any guidance on how to use this field?

Answer (score 0):

This is undocumented, beta behaviour yet. The @ means that the open() method needs more time to open the file (due network traffic). Just iterate over open() until you receive something else than '@'. Don't forget to sleep() between the iterations to allow the network stack doing its job.

Comment: Thanks. After first 1 second sleep (and before I had re-called open(), it crashed). Just before the 'BAD ACCESS' the  dump included:

......  '<+1026> at SuperpoweredHTTP.cpp
    0x1081cf0d4 <+200>:  leaq   0x24bd5(%rip), %r12       ; "URL is NULL."
    0x1081cf0db <+207>:  jmp    0x1081cf413               ; <+1031> at SuperpoweredHTTP.cpp
    0x1081cf0e0 <+212>:  leaq   0x24c43(%rip), %r12       ; "Filename is NULL." ...... 

Which looks like the URL or filename was not supplied in the original call - but the URL was!

Comment: Hi Gabor - trying again.. same issue.. here's the relevant part of the dump, just before message: Progressive Download (38): EXC_BAD_ACCESS..........0x10d42ac77 <+219>:  jmp    0x10d42afa3               ; <+1031> at SuperpoweredHTTP.cpp
    0x10d42ac7c <+224>:  movq   %rbx, -0xc0(%rbp)
    0x10d42ac83 <+231>:  movl   %r14d, -0xc8(%rbp)
    0x10d42ac8a <+238>:  movq   %r13, %rdi
    0x10d42ac8d <+241>:  callq  0x10d42d3d6               ; symbol stub for: strlen
    0x10d42ac92 <+246>:  shlq   $0x20, %rax  <----- FAILS HERE

Comment: Use SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer::setTempFolder.